# CommandArgument DataBinding Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a sql dataset gridview table which displays values from the database. I am trying to point my commandargument toward the compName variable within my SQL dataset (as in the code below) but I keep getting the following error:

"DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'compName'."

My C# code:

```
protected void searchTheDB()
{
    string s = "SELECT compName As 'Company/Organization Name', btcAddr As 'Bitcoin Address', Premium_User as 'Premium User'," + 
    "upvote as 'Upvotes',downvote As 'Downvotes' FROM clientDataTable WHERE compName LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'";

    try
    {
        SqlConnection forSearch = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter search = new SqlDataAdapter(s, forSearch);
        DataSet dB = new DataSet();
        search.Fill(dB);
        searchGridView.DataSource = dB;
        searchGridView.DataBind();
        searchBox.Text = String.Empty;
    }
    catch (SqlException exp)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sorry, the website is experiencing difficulties, please try again, error: ", exp);
    }
}
```

asp.net code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="searchGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="10" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="161px" Width="935px" CellSpacing="5" HorizontalAlign="Justify" BorderStyle="Solid" OnRowCommand="searchGridView_RowCommand">
                     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                     <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField>
                              <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:Button ID="DownButton" runat="server" CommandName="Upvote" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("compName")%>' Text="Upvote"> </asp:Button>
                              <asp:Button ID="UpButton" runat="server" CommandName="Downvote" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("compName")%>' Text="Downvote"> </asp:Button>
                              </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                     </Columns>

                     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                     <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                     <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                     <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                 </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note how your query looks like:

```
SELECT compName As 'Company/Organization Name'
```

There is no column named `compName` in resulting set, only `Company/Organization Name`. And therefore the data set object knows nothing about `compName`. So theoretically your data binding should look like this:

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Company/Organization Name")%>'
```

In practice however I am not completely sure such a column name will work fine, because of space (less concerned) and forward slash (more concerned). So I would consider simplifying column aliases, or even getting rid of them altogether - you are not going to use them for anything other than data binding anyway, right?